# ¿Cómo convertir char de varios caracteres a int y float en C?

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo C y quiero convertir una cadena de números a entero, y la otra cadena de texto convertirla a decimales pero no he podido, este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
char numeros[] = "265467";
char numeros2[] = "3.141592654";
int conversion = numeros -'0';
float conversion2 = numeros2 -'0';

printf("%d",conversion);
printf("%f",conversion2);
}
```

Al copilarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

incompatible types when initializing type 'float' using type 'char *'

Cómo podría solucionarlo, o que otros métodos podría usar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que la librería estándar C ya trae una función (`scanf()`) que lee del teclado una cadena de caracteres y la puede procesar para extraer de ella enteros, flotantes, etc mediante cadenas de formato, no es de extrañar que tenga otra función que haga exactamente lo mismo pero sin necesidad de leerlo del teclado, sino pasándole directamente la cadena que quieres procesar.

Esta función se llama `sscanf()` y se usa igual que `scanf()` sólo que añadiéndole un parámetro más (el primero) que sería el puntero a la cadena que quieres procesar. En tu caso por tanto se usaría así:

```
void main(){
  char numeros[] = "265467";
  char numeros2[] = "3.141592654";
  int conversion;
  float conversion2;

  sscanf(numeros, "%d", &conversion);
  sscanf(numeros2, "%f", &conversion2);
  printf("%d\n",conversion);
  printf("%f\n",conversion2);
}
```

Ten en cuenta no obstante que `sscanf()` puede devolver un resultado arbitrario si la cadena que le pasas no contiene datos interpretables como entero (en el primer caso) o flotante (en el segundo).

Comment: La funcion sscanf() , se podria usar para convertir de int a char y float?

Comment: no, pero tienes `sprintf()` para convertir de diferentes tipos a cadena (funciona como printf pero no saca nada por pantalla sino que lo deja en la cadena cuyo puntero le pases como primer parámetro, debes asegurarte de que haya sitio para los caracteres). Para convertir de int a float o viceversa no necesitas funciones, basta asignar a la variable del tipo destino.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, me podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo de como usar sprinter() por favor

Comment: `int x=123; char s[50]; sprintf(s, "%d", x);` dejará en `s` la cadena `"123"`.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar la función [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) para convertir una cadena en un `int` y [`atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) en un `float`.

Así:

```
int conversion = atoi(numeros);
float conversion2 = atof(numeros2);
```

O mejor, [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) si quieres leer un `long` o valores lo suficientemente pequeños para caber en un `int`. Te permite conocer donde termina el número en la cadena e indicar una base:

```
char* final;
long numero = strtol(numeros, &final, 10);
```

De manera similar, existe [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) para convertir a `float`, aunque sin poder indicar base:

```
char* final;
float numero = strtof(numeros, &final);
```

Puedes ver una comparación sobre los diferentes métodos de convertir cadenas en números [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866001/13419694).

---

Si lo deseas también puedes escribir tus propias funciones para realizar las conversiones. Por ejemplo, para enteros:

```
int convertir(char* cadena, int largo){
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){
        char caracter = cadena[i];
        if (caracter < '0' || cadena > '9')
            break;

        n *= 10;
        n += caracter - '0';
    }
    return n;
}
```